# Fetch wikipedia articles query optimization in mysql wikipedia Database

Tags: mysql, optimization, explain

I have imported the Wikipedia database to a local MySQL database and I wrote a query to fetch wiki pages.

My query is as follows :

```
SELECT
  p.page_title,
  p.page_id,
  t.id,
  text.old_text
FROM wikipedia_en.page p
  INNER JOIN wikipedia_en.categorylinks cl
         ON  cl.cl_from = p.page_id AND cl.cl_type = 'page'
         AND p.page_namespace = 0
         AND p.page_is_redirect = 0
  INNER JOIN wikipedia_en.revision ON revision.rev_id = p.page_latest
  INNER JOIN wikipedia_en.text ON text.old_id = revision.rev_text_id

   -- filter out pages with no topic 
  INNER JOIN topics.topics t  ON cl.cl_to = t.topic
LIMIT 520000, 10000;
```

The query takes about 2s if the `LIMIT` offset starts at 0 but as the offset grows up (e.g 520000) the query execution takes a remarkable time ( e.g for and offset of 520000 it takes about 4min )

Here is the query Explain Plan :

```
+----+-------------+----------+--------+------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type   | possible_keys                                  | key        | key_len | ref                               | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t        | ALL    | topics_topic_index                             | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                              | 141413 |                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cl       | ref    | PRIMARY,cl_timestamp,cl_sortkey                | cl_sortkey | 258     | topics.t.topic,const              |     14 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p        | eq_ref | PRIMARY,name_title,page_redirect_namespace_len | PRIMARY    | 4       | wikipedia_en.cl.cl_from           |      1 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | revision | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                        | PRIMARY    | 4       | wikipedia_en.p.page_latest        |      1 |                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | text     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                        | PRIMARY    | 4       | wikipedia_en.revision.rev_text_id |      1 |                          |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
```

I'm asking if there is a way to optimize this query using subqueries or temporary tables.

Comment: Please use `ON` for things that tie the tables together, and move "filters" to a `WHERE` clause. Without `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, we can't give specific advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OFFSET` must locate, but skip over, the rows.  If you can "remember where you left off", performance may be significantly better.

But there is a worse problem with your query.  Since there is no `ORDER BY`, the optimizer is free to provide the rows in any order it likes, thereby leading to missing or duplicated rows.

Even if you add an `ORDER BY`, `OFFSET` can give miss or duplicate rows if the table is being added to or deleted from.

Read my [*blog*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/) on this problem, then start over on your query.

Comment: Thank you Rick, I've read your blog post and It was very helpful, I omitted the offset and I used "left off" and the query perfommance is better now.